# Double c# value changes to 0.0 in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

my application is Windows Forms (VS2010 C#); I set a double variable at the beginning of the form as:

```
private double Wwidth;
```

Then I change the its value when I open a file:

```
 Wwidth = image.WindowWidth;
```

The value of Wwdith equals `265.0`.  When I select a trackbar,

```
private void tbrWidth_Scroll(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            double newWidth = tbrWidth.Value;
            double wd = Wwidth - newWidth;
...}
```

the value of Wwdith changes to `0.0`?

Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't on a **new instance** (or just: a different instance) of that type of form?

Comment: Please provide more information about `Wwidth` to make it easier to solve the issue :)

Comment: @user373721 find all usages of `Wwidth` and verify if there any other places where you modify it

Comment: You must be dealing with multiple instances or code that executes in an order you're not expecting it to. I think you need to provide more code for us to look at.

Comment: Thank you all your comments help to check my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables don't change themselves. So there are two possibilities:

1. some bit of code you've forgotten about changed it
2. it is a different instance

To rule out 2, you could put (in the two places):

```
Debug.WriteLine(
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(this));
```

If you get the same number printed from both places, you're probably still in the same instance. To rule out 1 - change it and put a break-point in:

```
private double _wwidth;
private double Wwidth {
    get { return _wwidth; }
    set { _wwidth = value; } // <==== put a breakpoint here
}
```

Now you should stop automatically at any code that is changing the value